# What's the probability of getting $5$ different numbers but not any $6$ when throwing $5$ dice?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, dice

**I have $5$ dice, I throw them at once. What is the probability of getting $5$ unique numbers, i.e., $1\ \  \&\ \  2\ \  \&\ \  3\ \  \&\ \  4\ \  \&\ \  5$ in any order BUT NOT any $6$?**

Of course they can be in any order as long as all $5$ dice are all unique numbers but not any $6$. I presume number of possibilities is divided by $6$ to the power of $5$ ($7776$)? But I do not know the number of possible permutations for $5$ unique numbers, excluding a $6$. **Please help.**

The question has an actual usefulness for me.

> What is the probability of getting $5$ different numbers but not any $6$ when throwing $5$ dice at once?

Comment: There are $6^5$ possible rolls, of which $5!$ satisfy your requirements so...

Comment: The number of "favourables" is, as you almost said, the number of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. You probably know how many of these there are.

Comment: What is the "actual usefulness for you" of this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, there are $5!=120$ different permutations of $5$ numbers, and as you wrote, there are $6^5=7776$ equiprobable outcomes, so the probability is

$$
\frac{120}{7776}=\frac5{324}\approx1.54\%\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks, had forgotten basic permutations.

Answer (score 1):

You can have $5!$ cases for the $5$ different numbers, and  clearly, you have $6^5$ cases as the total ones. So, the answer is $\color{red}{\frac{5!}{6^5}}$.

Comment: You are welcome!